# Erro ao converter BigInt para inteiro utilizando lambda

Tags: c#, sql-server, conversão-de-tipo

No banco de dados o tipo está `BigInt` e no C# estou tentando converter para `int` e ele consegue converter, mas quando chega na instrução *lambda*, dá erro.

```
 long codpro = Int64.Parse(tb_CodigoProduto.Text.Substring(0,14));
 db = (from p in data.Produtos where p.ProCodInt == codpro select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Você está convertendo para `long` não `int` e isto está correto. Sem sabemos o erro que dá fica um pouco complicado ajudar. Quando você faz uma pergunta com um código que dá um erro, você deve postar esse erro, onde exatamente dá, em que circunstâncias, todas as partes relevantes do código e se possível um código que possa reproduzi-lo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: "the 'ProCodInt' property on 'Produtos' could not be set to a 'Int64' value.You must this property to a non-null value of 'Int32'"

Comment: Qual é o tipo de `ProCodInt`? Seria um `int`? Ou um `int?`?

Comment: [ProCodInt] [bigint] NOT NULL

Comment: Precisa do tipo de `p.ProCodInt`, talvez seja bom colocar toda a estrutura do tipo de `p`.

Comment: Eu desisto, espero que alguém consiga retirar de você a informação necessária ou consiga te dar uma solução mesmo que você não passe a informação necessária.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Int64 procod = Int64.Parse(string);
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer, @BrunoRodrigues? Declarar a variável como `Int64` resolveu o seu problema?

Comment: Eu postei a resposta sobre o que resolveu o meu problema e obrigado pela ajuda a todos! e quem resolveu foi eu mesmo!

Comment: Você pode ter resolvido o problema mas não desta forma. Esta sintaxe sequer existe. O problema provavelmente era outro e foi resolvido de outra forma mesmo. Pelo código apresentado era impossível resolver.